# Running a set of standard nosetests functions in different conditions

Tags: python, unit-testing, nosetests

I'm trying to run a series of the same unit tests, but under different conditions. What I wanted to do was have 3 separate test classes that would import the same list of tests and run them. However, each test relies on class data.

I tried to set up each class individually and then import the test functions with

```
import Systems

...

for callable in Systems.__dict__.values():
    try:
        setattr(cls, 'test_' + callable.__name__, callable(cls))
        print callable.__name__
    except TypeError:
        pass
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

but while the test functions run, nosetests doesn't output the actual test results of each.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Are any exceptions raised? Maybe you should see if TypeError or AttributeError actually turn up anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try decorating your test functions in module `Systems` as nose tests:

```
from nose.tools import istest

@istest
def func1(...)
```

Most likely because you are naming functions on the fly, nose does not think those are actual tests.